# How can I incorporate constraints to optimize a function in a PSO (particle swarm optimization) model in Python

Tags: python

I'm really new to Python and I'm trying to build an algorithm to optimize economic energy dispatch with environmental constraints for at least 3 pollutants.  The objective function to minimize cost is

```
sum(cost_coefficients[i] * energy[i] for i in units)
```

I took the same structure from some examples I found on the net. In order to visualize the info in fuel Cost vs Power would I need to define x as power variable and y as cost_coefficients?
Additionally, would like to know how could I include the expressions for the environmental constraints

I just replaced on return the function to optimize

```
num_particles = 50
max_iterations = 100
search_space = [(-10, 10), (-10, 10)]  # Define the search space for optimization
inertia_weight = 0.5
cognitive_weight = 1.5
social_weight = 2.0

class Particle:
    def __init__(self, dimension):
        self.position = [random.uniform(d[0], d[1]) for d in search_space]
        self.velocity = [random.uniform(-1, 1) for _ in range(dimension)]
        self.personal_best_position = self.position.copy()
        self.personal_best_fitness = float('inf')
def fitness_function(position):
    # Replace this with your specific fitness evaluation logic
    x, y = position
    return sum(cost_coefficients[i] * energy[i] for i in units)

swarm = [Particle(len(search_space)) for _ in range(num_particles)]

global_best_position = None
global_best_fitness = float('inf')

for iteration in range(max_iterations):
    for particle in swarm:
        # Update velocity
        for i in range(len(search_space)):
            r1, r2 = random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)
            cognitive_component = cognitive_weight * r1 * (particle.personal_best_position[i] - particle.position[i])
            social_component = social_weight * r2 * (global_best_position[i] - particle.position[i])
            particle.velocity[i] = inertia_weight * particle.velocity[i] + cognitive_component + social_component

        # Update position
        for i in range(len(search_space)):
            particle.position[i] += particle.velocity[i]

        # Evaluate fitness
        fitness = fitness_function(particle.position)

        # Update personal best
        if fitness < particle.personal_best_fitness:
            particle.personal_best_fitness = fitness
            particle.personal_best_position = particle.position.copy()

        # Update global best
        if fitness < global_best_fitness:
            global_best_fitness = fitness
            global_best_position = particle.position.copy()

    print(f"Iteration {iteration}: Best Fitness = {global_best_fitness}, Best Position = {global_best_position}")
```

I get an error TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: for the question asked in the title: to impose the constraints either simply reject any particles in the swarm that don't satisfy them or simply make the cost function so large For non-compliant particles that these will never be chosen as global minimum anyway. You have a lot of bugs of similar form in your code: you initialise things as "None" and then try and carry out arithmetic and/or indexing operations on them. Better initialisation would solve most of these. You should also develop code incrementally, not check it once it's already 50 lines+.

Comment: there are **many** undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)